# Django: Staticfiles are creating but django failed to find staticfiles and look inside static folder

Tags: django

It was working fine, but for some reason, I have to change the staticfiles code and from there problem occurs.

`settings.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blackportfolio/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Staticfiles are creating my all css files are getting copy in staticfiles, browser also getting the staticfiles name `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.2f83ab2e5052.css">`

But its not searching them in `static_root(staticfiles)` it still searching them in static `python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 styles.css` but it returns with `C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vir1\blackportfolio\blackportfolio/static
  C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vir1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static`

the command I type.

```
manage.py collectstatic --clear
manage.py runserver --insecure.
```

project structure.

```
C:.
├───blackportfolio
│   ├───static
│   │   ├───admin
│   │   │   ├───css
│   │   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │   │       └───select2
│   │   │   ├───fonts
│   │   │   ├───img
│   │   │   │   └───gis
│   │   │   └───js
│   │   │       ├───admin
│   │   │       └───vendor
│   │   │           ├───jquery
│   │   │           ├───select2
│   │   │           │   └───i18n
│   │   │           └───xregexp
│   │   └───images
│   └───__pycache__
├───portfolio
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───staticfiles
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   │   └───vendor
│   │   │       └───select2
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           ├───select2
│   │           │   └───i18n
│   │           └───xregexp
│   └───images
└───templates
```

Comment: Set up absolute path STATIC_ROOT = "C:\blackportfolio\static"

Comment: It'll work in dev, but not in production.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific. You did not mention "prod" in your question at all. Note, `browser` and `findstatic` have nothing in common. `findstatic` collects files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` (not only) into `STATIC_ROOT`. "Browser" refers static files via `STATIC_URL` (hrefs in rendered HTML are generated based on this option).

When `DEBUG=true` - Django does the mapping job and maps URLs starting with `STATIC_URL` to `STATIC_ROOT` folder. On prod, when `DEBUG=false`, Django does not do this job - webserver has to do this.

So configure your Nginx (or other web server) to something like

```
location /static/ /* STATIC_URL */
{
    alias C:\Users\HP\Desktop\vir1\blackportfolio\staticfiles; /* STATIC_ROOT */
}
```

Deploying static files on prod is mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production) and has been [discussed many times on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226357/django-nginx-static-files-404).

Comment: ```STATICFILES_DIRS``` files are copying to ```STATIC_ROOT``` but it still searching staticfiles in static folder, in production it fails.